# Can't retrieve variable from php

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, smarty

**PHP FILE:**

```
<?php

#Communication with the API
require_once 'api.php';
$cloudkey = new CloudKey($user_id, $api_key);


if(isset($_FILES["FileInput"]) && $_FILES["FileInput"]["error"]== UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
{
    //Deleted Code: putting the uploaded files in my server.

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['FileInput']['tmp_name'], $UploadDirectory.$NewFileName ))
       {

 $video_file = "/home/george/public_html/q/"; 
 $video_file = $video_file . $NewFileName; 

#Sending the video from my server to the cloud server
$res = $cloudkey->file->upload_file($video_file);

#The cloud server will create a link
$source_url = $res->url;

#The cloud server will convert the video very fastly
while(1) {
    #Deleted Code: Conversion
    if ($asset->status == 'ready') {
        # A lot of code. It will convert the videos here and if it succeeds it will stop.
    break;
    # If the conversion fails, display error
    } else if ($asset->status == 'error') {
        echo "Error while transcoding the media\n";
    }
    sleep(1);
}


# Getting the URL of a thumbnail
echo $thumb = $cloudkey->media->get_stream_url(array('id' => $media_id, 'asset_name' => 'jpeg_thumbnail_source'));

    }else{
        die('error uploading File!');
    }

}
else
{
    die('Something went wrong!');
}
?>
```

**HTML FILE:**

```
  {literal}
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function() { 
    var options = { 
            target:   '#output',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
            beforeSubmit:  beforeSubmit,  // pre-submit callback 
            success:       afterSuccess,  // post-submit callback 
            uploadProgress: OnProgress, //upload progress callback 
            resetForm: true        // reset the form after successful submit 
        }; 


//function after succesful file upload (when server response)
function afterSuccess()
{
    $('#loading-img').hide(); //hide submit button
    $('#progressbox').fadeOut(); //hide progress bar
    //I WANT TO INSERT SOMETHING HERE.
}



//progress bar function
function OnProgress(event, position, total, percentComplete)
{
   //DOES NOT INTEREST YOU
}); 

</script>


{/literal} 

<div id="output"></div>
```

I am using smarty template engine. I have an html upload form that will communicate with a php file ***progressupload.php*** where the php file will convert the video (using API services) and brings back a response when it finishes.

When the user uploads the video file, ajax will take over show the percentage (in html), and it will send the file to ***progressupload.php***   and when the ***progressupload.php***  finishes the conversion it will output everything echoed in the **php** by simply putting this in the html file (I don't know why): `<div id="output"></div>`.

**WHAT I WANT:**

When  ***progressupload.php*** finishes the conversion, it will generate a thumbnail (screenshot) and store its link in `$thumb`. I want to retrieve `$thumb` and show it to the user using jquery.

Now if you look at the HTML Code, `afterSuccess()` is the function where I want to show the thumbnail to the user:

```
function afterSuccess()
{
    $('#loading-img').hide(); //hide submit button
    $('#progressbox').fadeOut(); //hide progress bar
    //I WANT TO SHOW THE THUMBNAIL HERE.
}
```

I deleted a lot of unnecessary code that could've distracted you. Remember that I am using smarty template engine, my html file does not end with **.php**, I cannot echo the variable directly. How can  I retrieve the php variable and put it in a jquery method after the variable is created.

I have a suspicion that if you retrieve the variable directly on page load, it will not succeed in getting `$thumb` since the link needs time to be created (uploading, conversion). How can I retrieve that `$thumb`?

Comment: This is no problem if you use proper formating for the output of your PHP file, e.g. JSON.

Comment: Note: You should rethink your whole approach, you will run into timeouts if you wait for the conversion of large files. Let a background-process handle the conversion and just return the status.

Comment: What kind of timeouts? And why?

Comment: Do you know fast solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using jQuery.ajax();
First parameter in the $.ajax 'success' callback is what returned from the server side.

```
function afterSuccess( response /** this is what returned from your server **/ )
{
    $('#loading-img').hide(); //hide submit button
    $('#progressbox').fadeOut(); //hide progress bar
    //I WANT TO INSERT SOMETHING HERE.

    console.log(response); // here you can access your $thumbnail
    // below code is untested but it should work
    // $("#output").html("<img src='"+response+"' class='thumbnail' />");
}
```